# Is there a way to compare the content / check for equality of 2 data.tables while ignoring class differences of cols

Tags: r, data.table

Having an input file as `.dta`, I imported it first using `haven::read_dta()` and then exported it as `.csv` file using `data.table::fwrite()`. Then I imported the `.csv` file using `data.table::fread()`.

---

I get the follwing tables:

```
dt_dta <- setDT(read_dta(file_path_dta))
fwrite(dt_dta, "csv_file")
dt_csv <- fread(file_path_csv)
```

---

I wanted to check for equality but this is what my methods print as a result of the equivalence check.

```
> all.equal.character(dt_dta, dt_csv)
[1] "'is.NA' value mismatch: 3115 in current 1273 in target"

> all_equal(dt_dta, dt_csv)
[1] "- Different types for column `abc`: double vs integer\n- Different types for column `bcd`: character vs integer ...
```

Basically, the `read(dta)` function reads in most of the data as character, even if it is a numeric column, while the `fread()` imported data.table correctly has them stored as integer.

---

**EDIT**

````
arsenal::comparedf(dt_dta, dt_csv) 

## Function Call: 
# Output: ```comparedf(x = dt_dta, y = dt_csv)```

# Shared: 22 non-by variables and 15839 observations.
# Not shared: 0 variables and 0 observations.

# Differences found in 3/16 variables compared.
# 22 variables compared have non-identical attributes.
````

Inspecting the `dt_dta` data.table, I saw that it stores various attributes of the variables that the `dt_csv` does not.

```
dt_dta$abc
..- attr(*, "label")=chr("An auto-generated identifier".)
..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%12.0g"
```

---

Now my question: Is there **any way to check for equality of the data** (in the sense of the same content) not for them being identical (in the sense of same col classes etc.). I want the conditional check to **ignore differences in col classes.** The only way I see it, is that I can coerce the column classes of the `dt_dta` table manually to match those of the `dt_csv` and then repeat the check.

Essentially, I assume that the export to another file type and subsequent import shouldn't cause any potential data integrity issues, right?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps comparing with all columns set to character?

```
library( data.table )
DT1 <- data.table( x = 1:2 )
DT2 <- data.table( x = c("1", "2") )
DT2;DT2

all.equal( DT1, DT2 )
#[1] "Datasets have different column modes. First 3: x(numeric!=character)"

all.equal( DT1[, lapply(.SD, as.character )], DT2[, lapply(.SD, as.character )] )
# [1] TRUE
```

also, make sure to take a look at the arguments of the `all.equal`-funciton to see if some of them fit your eneds

Comment: Thanks Wimpel! I thought that what you proposed was actually already implemented in ```all.equal.as.character()``` but your method leads to 'only' "Column 'ADDR1': 2 string mismatches" for whatever reason that I can live with. 

The aforementioned method actually just outputs "15 string mismatches". I am bumped to why there actually is a difference but hey...

Inintally I had to encode all missing values "" stored as character in the ```dt_dta``` data.table using ```dt_dta %>% na_if("")```. Then both methods worked, albeit with slightly different results....